# Need some assistance with LISTAGG options

Tags: sql, xml, string, oracle, listagg

`LISTAGG` has a 4000 character limitation.  Can anyone help with this nightmarish query?

Hi, I have this bad code in a query which feeds an application.   In this form, the query has no real criteria.  And because of that, `LISTAGG` is hitting the 4000 character limit.

Is there any other option here?  Based on how everything is concatenated, I am not seeing a simple answer:

```
SELECT 
    email,
    first_name,
    last_name, 
    LISTAGG(
        type_id 
        ||','|| type_status 
        ||','|| filename 
        ||','|| status_id
        ||','|| status_message 
        ||','|| TO_CHAR(upload_date,'MM/DDYYYY') 
        ||','|| broker 
        ||','|| quarter 
        ||','|| quarter_year
        ||':'
    ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY upload_date DESC) filenames
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            b.surrogate_key, 
            b.email,
            b.type_id, 
            DECODE(a.file_type,NULL,0,1) type_status, 
            a.quarter, 
            a.quarter_year, 
            a.broker, 
            a.upload_date, 
            a.filename, 
            a.status_id, 
            b.first_name, 
            b.last_name, 
            a.status_message
        FROM 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    (editor || '~' || file_type) surrogate_key,
                    file_type, 
                    quarter, 
                    quarter_year, 
                    broker,
                    filename,
                    upload_date,
                    status_id, 
                    status_message
                FROM upload_history
                ORDER BY upload_date DESC
            ) a, 
            (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                    (email||'~'||type_id) surrogate_key, 
                    email, 
                    type_id, 
                    first_name, 
                    last_name
                FROM issuers
                CROSS JOIN file_types 
            ) b
        WHERE 
            b.surrogate_key = a.surrogate_key(+)
    ) 
GROUP BY 
    email,
    first_name, 
    last_name, 
    type_id, 
    quarter, 
    quarter_year;
```

Comment: So you really want that result of a string that is > 4K?

Answer (score 1):

The classical workaround the 4000 chars limitation of `LISTAGG` is to use [`XMLAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions215.htm), as explained in [this famous AskTom post](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2196162600402#2454891700346769151).

The syntax is a bit convoluted. In your use case, you would need to replace this :

```
    LISTAGG(
        type_id 
        ||','|| type_status 
        ||','|| filename 
        ||','|| status_id
        ||','|| status_message 
        ||','|| TO_CHAR(upload_date,'MM/DDYYYY') 
        ||','|| broker 
        ||','|| quarter 
        ||','|| quarter_year
        ||':'
    ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY upload_date DESC) filenames
```

With :

```
    REPLACE(REPLACE(
        XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("a", 
            type_id 
            ||','|| type_status 
            ||','|| filename 
            ||','|| status_id
            ||','|| status_message 
            ||','|| TO_CHAR(upload_date,'MM/DDYYYY') 
            ||','|| broker 
            ||','|| quarter 
            ||','|| quarter_year
            ||':'
        ) ORDER BY upload_date DESC).getClobVal(),
    '<a>', ''), '</a>', ',') filenames
```

Comment: This is very awesome.   I'd like to know exactly how this XMLAGG & XMLELEMENT work......I've never seen this.   And is it the prefer method over LISTAGG?

Comment: Not necessarily "preferred". XMLAGG etc are part of the XML Developer kit that comes with the database. Its primary function is about parsing, processing and generating XML documents. The example above is actually generating a XML document and then we are stripping off the tags to leave us with just the concatenated data.  All the XML functionality is here https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adxdb/index.html

Comment: @LandonStatis : XMLELEMENT generates a XML fragment, XMLAGG aggregates them.  Unless you are hitting 4000 chars, I would suggest using LISTAGG, which is primarily designed to aggregate strings, and switch to XML* functions as workaround